# armv8 inline asm compile fail on xcode 6.2

Tags: xcode, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm trying to compile a inline asm (in *.h) using Xcode6.2 with target to iPad air2(aarch64)

```
    int16x8_t tmp16x8_4,tmp16x8_5,tmp16x8_6;
    __asm__("cmgt %v0.8h, %v1.8h, %v2.8h"::"w"(tmp16x8_4), "w"(tmp16x8_5), "w"(tmp16x8_6))
```

but compile failure "invalid operand in inline asm:'cmgt ${0:v}.8h,${1:v}.8h,${2:v}.8h'", I try to add \() while still fail.

```
    __asm__("cmgt %v0\().8h, %v1\().8h, %v2\().8h"::"w"(tmp16x8_4), "w"(tmp16x8_5), "w"(tmp16x8_6))
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about clang, but gcc complains that `%v` is an invalid operand prefix, which seems perfectly reasonable since the constraint already says it's a vector register, and it assembles fine without the `v`.

Comment: Is this for some experiment or is that the code you really need to execute? If so, why not use intrinsics and then the code will compile for both 32 and 64-bit ARM

Comment: @Notlikethat BitBank thanks for suggestion from both of you. I tried both, both works. I don't prefer intrinsic because the dissemble code not efficient. Thanks for both of your again.